# Coderush Unit Test Runner and Assert.Inconclusive

Tags: nunit, coderush

Can the coderush unit test runner recognise an NUnit Inconclusive assertion as something other than a failure. Perhaps something more like ignored rather than failed?
I am comparing this to resharpers treatment of inconclusive assertions. Is so do I need to configure this and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize, but CodeRush can't do that at the moment. If you post a suggestion via the DevExpress [Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/), they will consider implementing it in the future.